# Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

Trying to read an input that coincides with abjadMapV. Then return the char in AbjadMap. But i keep getting this error.

```
def show(ln):

    abjadMapV=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
              10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,
              100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,
              1000,29]

    abjadMap=['\u0627','\u0628','\u062C','\u062F','\u0647','\u0648','\u0632','\u062D','\u0637',
          '\u064A','\u0643','\u0644','\u0645','\u0646','\u0633','\u0639','\u0641','\u0635',
          '\u0642','\u0631','\u0634','\u062A','\u062B','\u062E','\u0630','\u0636','\u0638',
          '\u063A','\uFEFC']
    abjadN=["alif","ba","jeem","dal","haa","waw","za","ha","da",
              "ya","kahf","laam","meem","noon","seen","ayn","fa","sadh",
              "qaf","ra","sheen","ta","tha","kha","thal","dhad","za",
              "gayn","lam alif"]

    i=0

    for i in enumerate(abjadMapV):
        if ln in abjadMapV[i] :
            print(i)
            print(abjadMap[i])
            return abjadMap[i]

    b=input()
    a=show(b)
    print(a)
```

Edited to new code trying to get show to return the index

```
def show(ln):

abjadMapV=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
          10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,
          100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,
          1000,29]

abjadMap=['\u0627','\u0628','\u062C','\u062F','\u0647','\u0648','\u0632','\u062D','\u0637',
      '\u064A','\u0643','\u0644','\u0645','\u0646','\u0633','\u0639','\u0641','\u0635',
      '\u0642','\u0631','\u0634','\u062A','\u062B','\u062E','\u0630','\u0636','\u0638',
      '\u063A','\uFEFC']
abjadN=["alif","ba","jeem","dal","haa","waw","za","ha","da",
          "ya","kahf","laam","meem","noon","seen","ayn","fa","sadh",
          "qaf","ra","sheen","ta","tha","kha","thal","dhad","za",
          "gayn","lam alif"]

i=0

for i in abjadMapV:

    if ln == i:
        return abjadMap.index(i)
```

b=input()
a=show(b)
print(a)

Comment: Probably also look at how [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The function enumerate returns tuple. So in line

```
print(abjadMap[i]) # i here is tuple.
```

And you have figured out that the list indices must be integer not Tuple. 
Therefore edit your code accordingly.
If you are not familiar with enumerate function look at the example given below:

```
l=['a','b','c']
k=enumerate(l)
```

enumerate function returns iterable object:
so k is an iterable object,

```
next(k)
```

gives the output:

```
(0,'a')
```

that means 0 is the index of a in list l.

```
for i in enumerate(l)
```

i is an tuple not an integer.

Comment: what should i do sorry im new to programming. Im trying to use the for loop to loop through the values  of AbjadMapV and then if the input is the same. return that index and display the values using print. in c++ you can do for (i=0;i<len(abjadMapV;i++), does enumerate do the same thing?

Comment: It depends on what is your expected output.

Comment: how would i make a for loop without enumerate then? that loops the list to find the expected value aka ln.

Comment: simply use for i in abjadMap:

Comment: when i use len() instead of enumerate. i get int object is not iterable

Comment: do more study and online tutorials. Dive into the basic datatypes, don't jump into complex  examples.

Comment: Edited tryin to get show to return index but i get none as a result from print

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` returns a list of tuples, each being an index-value pair. You may destructure while iterating through them to solve the issue:

```
for i,j in enumerate(abjadMapV):
    if ln in j: # j is the value i. e. j = abjadMap[i] 
        print(i) # i is the index
        print(abjadMap[i] )
        return abjadMap[i]
```

You may otherwise iterate through `range(len(abjadMapV))` and use the variable as the index.